# Is there a way to generate @Entity classes based on existing classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have somewhat big object model in my app, and want to decouple model definition from persistence layer. This is an example of class that I want to generate entity class from:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public abstract class AbstractAccount {
  protected Long id;
  protected AbstractProfile profile;
  protected AbstractAuthorization<AbstractRole> authorization;
  protected AbstractWallet wallet;
  protected AbstractActivityHistory<AbstractGameSessionRecord, AbstractOperationRecord> history;

  // Constructors and stuff...
}
```

Simply marking every class with @Entity, manipulating field annotations as well would be enough, but I really need to decouple them. I want to get entities like this:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public abstract class AccountEntity {
  public AccountEntity(AccountType accountType) {
    this.accountType = accountType;
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long id;

  @Embedded
  public AbstractWalletEntity walletEntity;

  @Embedded
  public AbstractProfileEntity profileEntity;

  @Embedded
  AbstractAuthorizationEntity authorizationEntity;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  public AccountType accountType;
}
```

Comment: If you have model mixed with persistanse layer, it would be easier to make model from persistance layer vs other way
i dont think there would be tool for it, but you can copy classes and remove all persistance annotations

Comment: How can I generate classes from entities then?

Comment: I would copy classes files to new location and then perform replace on new files replacing all imports from persistance packages than replacing all `@Id` , `@Column(.*)` etc, It would be semi manual but i dont think there is better way